# NSExpression to concatenate two KVC strings

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Scenario:
I have an NSObject 'A' representing a relationship between two other NSObjects 'B and C' respectively. Both B and C have properties (NSStrings) retrieved using KVC.

I would like to use NSExpression in the body of an 'A' accessor to derive a compound string. So:

```
[B valueForKey:@"oneString"] returns 'Foo'
[C valueForKey:@"oneString"] returns 'Bar'
// And I would like to dynamically form
[A valueForKey:@"oneString"] returns 'Foo:Bar'
```

I know the obvious of `'stringWithFormat'` but I need to allow for different expressions using different keyPaths determined at run-time.

Comment: Reading the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html), I see "Note that although Core Data supports evaluation of the predefined functions, it does not support the evaluation of custom predicate functions in the persistent stores (during a fetch)." It seems that concatenation is not among them, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Monolo I want to do this in memory, not looking to have it performed on the data store. The fact that 'A,B and C' are NSManagedObjects is not entirely relevant.

Comment: More specifically (just dug up the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html)), a `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingOneString` should do it, if I understand your requirements correctly. Together with an accessor that concatenates the strings in question, of course.

Comment: @Monolo I can't accept the answer as it ignores my point about not wanting to use (for numerous reasons) stringWithFormat. As I mentioned, this has to be determined at run time not development time.

Comment: Here is the deal, I 'proxy' the NSPropertyDescription and descendants to have a data drive UI that performs inferences using the NSxxxDescriptors in addition to 'userInfo'. In some cases I need to fabricate descriptors and in this case I want to store the expression in the 'userInfo' to evaluate as part of the proxy interface information request.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString*)key
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [self.a valueForKey:key], [self.b valueForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something to use at run time not at development time. Thanks for asking.

Comment: What I posted should work at run time — pass in any key string using `[A valueForKey:anyString];` and it'll return the concatenated values of that key from your child objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell the thoughts from comments out in a more complete answer:

You can define `oneString` as a readonly property:

```
@property (readonly) NSString* oneString;
```

Then define a custom accessor:

```
- (NSString *)oneString {
      // ... do your logic here
      NSString *firstStr = ...
      NSString *secondStr = ...
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", firstStr, secondStr];
}

+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingOneString {
     return [NSSet setWithObjects: @"self.a", @"self.b", @"self.c", nil]; 
}
```

<sub>Typed directly into the browser, so beware of typos</sub>